# I don't understand how to type the answer

Tags: python

Write a function named satisfaction that has 1 input (parameter). This parameter's value will be a string. The function should return the parameter's value concatenated with a space and then "beast".

i tried to do

```
def satisfaction (x) :

       x = '' + "beast"

return x
```

That didn't work or maybe I am typing it in wrong. I don't understand what to do here.

This is one sample test case :

`satisfaction("real")`, evaluates to `"real beast"`

Comment: Return statement should be inside of the function body.
Also why do you need the parameter x if you are not using it? Just return "beast" instead

Comment: Add an space at the beginning of 'beast'. And indent return with 4 spaces.

Comment: @Fed_Dragon *function should return the parameter's value concatenated with a space and then "beast"*

Comment: `That didn't work` isn't really a description of the problem. Please update the question with some sample inputs and outputs from your function and describe how they are wrong.

Comment: I added a sample test case on how it should evaluate to

Comment: And what does your code produce?

Comment: It is just to define a function to a concatenated value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What you were doing wrong:

You were simply assigning `"beast"` to `x`. Also, `''` this doesn't include space. To add a space use `' '`

```
def satisfaction (x) :

       x = '' + "beast" 

return x # You are returning x outside the function.
```

### This is how it should be done:

The `x` parameter is the input that you need to concatenate with      `beast`.

```
def satisfaction(x):
    return x + ' beast' # This returns input parameter with space, concatenated with beast.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
def satisfaction (x) :
       x += ' ' + "beast"
       return x
```

You missed the plus sign as well as the tabulation

Comment: Missed it. Should be correct now

Answer (score -1):

```py
def satisfaction(x):
    x += "beast"
    return x
```

You should use same amount of spaces as for assign. And you should actually use concat operation (`+=`)

Comment: Do you think this will yield the desire result? _the parameter's value concatenated with a space and then "beast"._

Comment: Still missing a space.